# React JS Navigator Call Directly

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Using React Native Navigator. I am able to successfully change scenes using 
`this.props.navigator.push()`
however, when I try calling the Navigator.push directly I am getting undefined errors.

Does anyone know how I can call it directly from a parent component?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `ref='navigator'` to the navigator, then calling this `refs.navigator.push`

Comment: ** `this.refs.navigator.push`